# Java code in Adapters API

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Java code in an adapter, however I can't find the API doc reference of the classes I receive in Java. i.e. com.worklight.common.js.util.JSObjectConverter

Is this API documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can see server side Java API reference here - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_worklight_java_server_side.html (open the "Java server-side API" section in the left frame).

The specific API you're asking about (JSObjectConverter) is internal undocumented API therefore you'll not find any documentation for it.